# Teamcity Build Error

Tags: build, teamcity

When I run my Automation test script locally its working absolutely fine without any error message. But when I run on server, I can see that its working fine, but at the end, instead of Pass status, it shows test failure.

```
Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 282.662 sec <<<
FAILURE!
allNumbersEditorsDraws(NumbersEditor.TestSuiteAdmin)  Time elapsed: 0.047 sec  <
<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'W-SL-DEVBUILD1', ip: '10.130.32.68', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:134)
       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:500)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
        at NumbersEditor.LoginPage.loginAdmin(LoginPage.java:32)
        at NumbersEditor.TestSuiteAdmin.allNumbersEditorsDraws(TestSuiteAdmin.java:18)


Results :

Failed tests:   allNumbersEditorsDraws(NumbersEditor.TestSuiteAdmin): Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?(..)

Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:50 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-26T10:41:18+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/328M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
12.4:test (default-test) on project NumbersEditor: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\BuildAgent\work\f3b21200f1a5caf2\Automation\target\su
refire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue when you are doing UI test with Selenium on virtual machines.
When you run your tests, your session should be active. So, if you are connected in remote desktop on the VM, the current script is working, but, if you exit, the current session disapear.

In order to make it works, you should leave the current remote session with a script :

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
)
```

Comment: Where shall I write this script? In my automation script, Drivermanager file or I write in TeamCity ???